# How do I close old tmux sessions

Tags: tmux

My server has many expired tmux sessions running. How can I quickly remove them without killing my active session.

One option is to find each session and type `tmux kill-session -t N` but this would be a lot of commands to type for 20 sessions. What are some other options?

Answer (score 2):

Kill all other sessions except the current one:

```
tmux kill-session -a
```

Comment: If your tmux is new enough you can also do it from tree mode - press `C-b s`, then tag the sessions you want to kill using `t` (they will be marked in bold), then press `:` and type `kill-session` at the `(N tagged)` prompt.